# Php Function, to extract link from short text

Tags: php

I am looking fo a function, to extract the mp3 source of this snippet of code:
`http://www.xyz.com/previews/speed_racer_preview.mp3 1930510 audio/mpeg`

i only need that part:
`http://www.xyz.com/previews/speed_racer_preview.mp3`

This part always has the same structure, only the source changes.

Answer (score 2):

If it's always formatted like that just use explode (it breaks a string into an array on a given character, in this case space):

```
$arr = explode(' ',$the_data_string);
$URL = $arr[0];
```

Hope this helps,

Lemiant

PS for more info you can read [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo substr($str, 0, strpos($str, ' '));
```

Comment: Both functions do not work. I think it is because of the empty spaces.

Comment: PS: what is "empty spaces"?!? O_o

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = explode(" ",$url);
```

the explode method return an array so:

```
$finalurl = $arr[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex you could use with one of [PHP's regex functions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html) (you may need to fiddle with it a bit, I just made this in BareGrep, have not written a full PHP function for you, but this should get you started, the quotes are not part of the regex of course):

```
" ([A-Za-z0-9_//:.]+[.]mp3) "
```

Comment: If you would suggest to use regex, then this one: "~^\S+~" will be **much** better.

Comment: I used this:`preg_match_all('!https?://[\S]+!', $file_url, $matches);`

Comment: @zerkms: Fair enough, I'm not particularly adept with regex expressions, I just wanted to make a posting about the general approach because nobody else had.

Comment: @chris: square brackets are superfluous for `\S` there

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression. All matches are saved into $result array.

```
$res = preg_match("/http:\/\/[^\s]+\.mp3/", $source, $result);
print_r($result); // Each index will be a different matched mp3, if there is more than one
```

The return value is a bool indicating if the match was positive.